# How to resolve promise in unit tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

After I added Promise in my componentDidMount tests ceased to pass. How can I resolve promise in componentDidMount? I need something like runOnlyPendingTimers but for Promise.

My test is:

```
it("should clear canvas on each frame draw", () => {
    mount(<CoinsAndStars stars={true} coins={true} DeviceSupport={DeviceSupport} />);
    ctxMock.clearRect = jest.fn();
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```

Comment: possible dupe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574492/promise-isnt-working-in-react-component-when-testing-component-using-jest)

Comment: You can either wrap this in Async/await out just put it in cascading .then blocks.

Comment: what you mean? I have .then in my componentDidMount

Comment: @Shammoo 
something like this?
`(async function() {
            mount(<CoinsAndStars stars={true} coins={true} DeviceSupport={DeviceSupport} />);
            ctxMock.clearRect = jest.fn();
            jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
            jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
        })();`

Comment: the previous doesn't change the behavior. can you share an excerpt of your `cdm` function? what are you trying to test?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for anyone come in handy. If you use promise in componentDidMount, in test you need await while mount will end

```
it("should clear canvas on each frame draw", async () => {
    await mount(<CoinsAndStars stars={true} coins={true} DeviceSupport={DeviceSupport} />);
    ctxMock.clearRect = jest.fn();
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(ctxMock.clearRect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```